# Does a voltage limit in a battery increase amperage over all?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, buck, amperage

I have an 18 V battery with a 4 Ah battery. If I limit the voltage output to 9 V with a buck converter or voltage regulator, how would limiting the voltage affect the amount of current output?

Comment: How much current would you expect the load to draw with a 9V battery instead of an 18V battery? A switching regulator and linear regulator will be different though. The first converts power between Volts and amps. The second burns off excess voltage as heat.

Comment: Also, just checking, you do realize that AH is not the same as amperage, right? Or current output? I ask because you specifically ask about "increase" which is very strange when you also asking about limiting the voltage.

Comment: I dont know too much about electronics, I'm just trying to see if limiting the voltage on this 18v 4ah battery to 9v will basically increase the amp hour to 8ah. Using a buck converter.

Comment: So you are not asking about increasing amperage/amps/A aka (fuel flow rate) at all. Nor are you truly asking about increasing Amp-hours/Ah (the size of your fuel  tank). You are asking about run-time which is would come about as a result of decreasing amperage. (I mean, you could increase the size of your fuel tank, but that's with different batteries).

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that with "amperage" you mean the total amount of Ampere-hours the battery can deliver and that with "limiting the voltage" you mean regulating the voltage of an 18V battery down to 9V.

If you had a buck converter that's 100% efficient, you would draw half the current from the 18V battery than would be delivered to the 9V side at the output of the buck converter. That would effectively make your 18V, 4Ah battery into a 9V, 8Ah battery (i.e. still a 72Wh battery, but at a lower voltage). In reality a buck converter is only 80-90% efficient.

With a *linear* 18V to 9V regulator, the battery would deliver the same amount of current at 18V at the converter's input as is delivered to the converter's output at 9V, halving the total amount of power delivered to the load and converting the other half to heat.

In reality the voltage of an 18V battery would not stay at 18V while the battery is being discharged but the regulated 9V output will, making the relationship between input and output current/power less straightforward than I've described here.